# Unabel to run hello-world cmd from snap in fedora 34

Tags: fedora, snap

I will appreciate it if anybody can tell me what's wrong here

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I had the same issue and guess what? You have used `sudo` to install packages from `sanp`.
So run your cmd using `sudo`. And see if its help let us know.

Comment: How could I miss this? I would have already tried this thing. You are great it's working.